# error while running bouncy castle algorithm in netbeans

Tags: java-me, netbeans-6.9, bouncycastle

I'm trying to run the bouncy castle algorithm following this [tutorial](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/tutorials/wi-encrypt/section4.html).

I'm using Netbeans 6.9, Java ME SDK 3.0, bouncy castle package `bcprov-ext-jdk16-146.jar`.

I'm using IDEA engine as encryption engine (as you can see by checking the tutorial).

My problem is that building the project the following preverification error occurs:

> Error preverifying class org.bouncycastle.asn1.ASN1GeneralizedTime
>   VERIFIER ERROR
>   org/bouncycastle/asn1/DERGeneralizedTime.(Ljava/util/Date;)V:
>
> Cannot find class java/util/SimpleTimeZone
>
> D:\my projects\testProject\nbproject\build-impl.xml:470:
>   Preverification failed with error code 1.

And when I run the project, it gives the error on this [image](http://goo.gl/PQDLq)

Can anyone pls tell me, what's the actual problem?
FYI, I'm using `CLDC-1.1` & `MIDP-2.1`.

Comment: You need to use the bouncycastle JME library.

Comment: @GregS, I've found the solution. Thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've got the answer to my problem. I've found these links while googling with my problem. If you are new,just like me in Java ME world & want to use Crypto fascination in your project, pls read the following links :

http://goo.gl/RZsJi
http://goo.gl/2xVLp

it'll work like a charm...

Happy programming :) :)